# Find EXE/File version of a file in OSX

Tags: macos

In Windows, you can go into a file's properties, then on the Details tab, there is a "File Version" listing.

Is there a way to see this same information in OSX?

Right now I'm looking at a specific file, it's a Windows EXE.  When I go a "get info" in OSX, I don't see a version listed, and there is nothing in the more info section.

Is it because it's a Windows EXE?  Or is there somewhere else I need to look?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PowerShell for Mac OS.

See snippet below. I'm using this for web app artifact downloaded from bamboo build server.

```
$info = Get-ItemProperty -Path "$($dir)\$($filename)\Deployment\WebApp\bin\ABB.NORRD.WebSite.dll"
$version = $info.VersionInfo.FileVersion
```

Answer (score -1):

It's because it's a Windows exe - there's no Mac version info to see.

Need to examine it from Windows/Parallels/ etc to get to the Windows-specific info. I don't know of any Mac utility that will extract it.

Comment: Ok, I kind of assumed this, but I wasn't sure if there was a way to still see it somehow.  I asked because I use a Mac as my main work computer, but obviously I deal with a lot of Windows stuff, so it would have been helpful to verify a file/exe version directly in OSX rather than having to download/open it separately in a VM or other server/system.

Comment: We could both hope someone knows of a Mac Util that can do it - would be useful on occasions, faster than throwing it at one of the Win machines I have here.

Comment: Was hoping as well, not an impossible mac issue, just something to parse it.  Was hoping GNU File would help, but that didn't show much at all.  Virustotal also shows exe details, but more on pure compiled content, less on user supplied metadata like I was hoping.